# C++ Ogre, Won't compile and run

Tags: c++, codeblocks, ogre

So i'm trying to make a game in c++ with OGRE. But i just can't get OGRE up and running.

I followed the tutorial on this website: http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Setting+Up+An+Application+-+CodeBlocks

But it just won't work.

I did notice the last lines in the tutorial:

"*You should now be able to compile and run your Ogre application. 
Well, maybe not until you've copied it to the Ogre sdk bin directory (or take resources.cfg and plugins.cfg from there). 
Or by copying Ogre dlls and media..* "

I really think this has something to do with the last lines in the tutorial (The quote just above this text).
But, i really don't know what i have to copy from the OGRE directory.

I get this error:

http://gyazo.com/b2ca05c8d13c6170e13c791fa7d4f24d

BTW, i use Code::Blocks, and MingGW.
AND i use a prebuilt OGRE SDK.

Thanks.

Just ask if you need to know anything :)

EDIT:

I got it to work! There were some problems with the options, not pointing to the right ogre directory. But this just leaves me with another error:

http://gyazo.com/23f52fcd8d083533d70fa23aeb28a2c8

I will go find out something about this error. I will ofcourse be happy if you could help me with this one too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the output error message (bottom of the screen).  It says that the compiler cannot find OgreBuildSettings.h file.  You must edit your project config file (.pro) so that the compiler can find this header file.  Or move stuff around so that the header file is somewhere in the project's path.

Comment: Thanks for answering :) I added the OgreBuildSettings.h to my project directory, and added it with the button: "Add files recurvesively". But i get the same error. I'll add a picture of the project directory.

Comment: I guess there's no other explanation, than yours. This problem MUST be because, it can't find the file. Therefore, I vote you as the best answer.